# Why doesn't my Tampermonkey script run on some website although there's no bug in the script

Tags: tampermonkey

I wrote a script to run in Tampermonkey. On most websites, a simple  `$("#loginLink")[0].click();` will click the link as soon as the website is loaded. But on some, even if I use

> 

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(document.getElementById("nextButton").click(), 1000);
  setInterval(document.getElementById("submitButton").click(), 1000);
 });
```

The script won't run. The Tampermonkey extension icon shows that the script is running on that website, which means I got the URL right. The script ran fine when I entered it into the console. But it won't run automatically by Tampermonkey. Can someone help me?
This is the website where the problem occurs:
[Link here](https://asso.hust.edu.vn/adfs/ls/?wtrealm=https%3A%2F%2Fctt.hust.edu.vn%2F&wctx=WsFedOwinState%3DG_-NXTTJq7P3kj6LCzeWQI8lqQj0j_Pq2-zmDz3WDSxfndY-kFdLGo247p8q9dmy4axZK7pYIWAHaCVQ5hdZtCo9YNB8kOdd_iIKKEZi-n8COAkEJ42aWABvBTTK2Fflgedh6IjLlaAouMSHQl_4vQ&wa=wsignin1.0&wreply=https%3A%2F%2Fctt.hust.edu.vn%2F)

Comment: Add `()=>` before each document.getElementById.

Comment: doesn't work tho

Comment: It means those sites don't have elements with such ids or something else in the script is incorrect. Show the full code, [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought . . .

Your script is using jQuery - is the Tampermonkey script loading jQuery as a required resource? You haven't posted your full code so I can't be sure you did. So, just in case: here's what you need to use jQuery in your TM script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         zerohedge.com
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @match        https://zerohedge.com/*
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
```

(You need that @require line if you do not have it...)